# Replace the first value of a 2d list to zero

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Having 2d list as below:

```
a = [[4.0, 4, 4.0], [3.0, 3, 3.6], [3.5, 6, 4.8]]
```

need to replace first value to zero.

```
a = [[0, 4, 4.0], [0, 3, 3.6], [0, 6, 4.8]]
```

I tried to iterate over the 2d list:

```
[i[0] for i in a]
```

Comment: Had this construction be possible (it is not), it should rather have been written `i[0]=0 for i in a` (without surrounding brackets, which create a new list). But `for i in a: i[0]= 0` works.

Answer (score 3):

Because you tag [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), you can do this without iterate like below:

```
import numpy as np

a_2 = np.asarray(a)
a_2[:, 0] = 0
# --^^^^ -> : -> mean all rows and (0) mean is column==0
print(a_2)
```

---

```
[[0.  4.  4. ]
 [0.  3.  3.6]
 [0.  6.  4.8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

we can use a slice on the left hand side of the assignment to overwrite the first element in each sub list with 0 (this is called slice assignment). the replacement is done inplace.

```
arr = [[4.0, 4, 4.0], [3.0, 3, 3.6], [3.5, 6, 4.8]]
for sub in arr:
    sub[0:1] = [0]
print(arr)
```

result is: `[[0, 4, 4.0], [0, 3, 3.6], [0, 6, 4.8]]`

Comment: Instead of `sub[0:1] = [0]` does `sub[0] = 0` work?

Comment: wwii, yes this is also working.

Answer (score 1):

if you're going to do it using list comprehension, you have to think in terms of generating a new list, and not modifying the original list in place:

```
a = [[4.0, 4, 4.0], [3.0, 3, 3.6], [3.5, 6, 4.8]]
b = [[0, *x[1:]] for x in a]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```py
example = [[4.0, 4, 4.0], [3.0, 3, 3.6], [3.5, 6, 4.8]]

# convert the first element of each list to 0
example = [[0, *x[1:]] for x in example]

print(example)
```

Comment: kind of strange how similar our code samples are :)